# When importing GSAP into my TypeScript project, the browser says it cannot find GSAP

Tags: typescript, gsap

I am working on a TypeScript project using THREE.js and GSAP. This is my first TypeScript so maybe it's something obviously I am missing but whenever I import GSAP into my project I get an error in the browser.

The app is using express as the server and compiling the TypeScript code with

```
"dev": "concurrently -k \"tsc -p ./src/server -w\" \"tsc -p ./src/client -w\" \"nodemon ./dist/server/server.js\""
```

So every time I make a change it compiles the TypeScript in the /dist folder which is where my index.html file is.

I have tried a number of different GSAP plugins and import styles but I get the same issue every time. Here is an example of me importing gsap into my file.

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { DrawSVGPlugin } from "gsap/DrawSVGPlugin";
gsap.registerPlugin(DrawSVGPlugin);
```

Then when I go to the browser I get an error in the console saying this.
[image]

I don't know if I need to add anything to my tsconfig.json file maybe? I have a couple of configurations for some relative paths for THREE.js so maybe I need something similar for GSAP?

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "outDir": "../../dist/client",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "/build/three.module.js": ["../../node_modules/three/src/Three"],
        "/jsm/*": ["../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/*"]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "node"
},
"include": [
    "**/*.ts"
]
}
```

The in the express server I am adding those static files like so

```
app.use('/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js')))
```

I hope this is easy but I a kind of lost on this one. I am also wondering if I maybe need to switch to webpack or something but I am trying to avoid it for now.

Comment: Did you install GSAP via npm? You can do using the .tgz file found in the ZIP download from the GreenSock website (to make sure it has your Club GreenSock plugins). See [the GSAP installation page](http://greensock.com/install/) for more info.

Comment: I installed via yarn, I was hoping to keep it all the same way I was doing all my other imports.

Comment: It's practically the same except you'd use `yarn add` instead of `npm install`. Again, it's covered in the installation docs.